# Build failed while using the static library file in Xcode 4.3.2,iOS

Tags: xcode, ios5, static-libraries

I am new to iOS.I created the static library file using http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/
When I using the static library file in another project it gives errors as

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Exact_Library", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me where I did wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your static library to your "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase. Click on your project in the left hand menu, then click the tab "Build Phases". Drag and drop your static library into the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.